# Kempner Series with bases other than 10

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Although the harmonic series $1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + \cdots$ diverges, we know that if we remove from the sum all the terms whose denominator expressed in base 10 contains a 9 digit, the series will converge.

Furthermore, the series will converge for any omitted digit (Kempner series).

I stumbled upon a book exercise that asks me to prove the convergence of every sum with removed digits for any numerical base b, for example:

Will the following sum:$1+\frac13 +\frac17 +\frac1{15}+\cdots$ (where all the positive integers that do not contain ”0” in the base 2 were removed) converge?

How can I prove it? Any help will be appreciated.(Sorry for my English)

Comment: The sum is majored by $1+\frac12 + \frac14 + \ldots = 2$.

Comment: Do you know how to prove it in base $10$? The idea is the same for an arbitrary base.

Answer (score 3):

[Cauchy's condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) is enough for proving convergence.

For instance, between $2^N$ and $2^{N+1}-1$ there is just one number (the last one) without zeroes in its binary representation, and

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n-1}$$
is quite trivially convergent. Another example: let $S=\{1,3,\ldots\}=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots\}$ be the set of positive integers for which the representation in base $7$ is free of $2$s. Between $7^N$ and $7^{N+1}-1$ there are $5\cdot 6^N$ elements of $S$, hence:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{s_n}\leq\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{\left|[7^m,7^{m+1}-1]\cap S\right|}{7^m}=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{6^m}{7^m}=7.$$

Comment: but how can I prove the general case for any base?

Comment: @mobzopi: in the same way, you have just to adjust the numbers ($7$ for the base and $2$ for the non-allowed digit).

Comment: sorry but what does # mean?

Comment: @mobzopi: cardinality of.